# Can't make video upload and autoplay to work in a custom theme in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm Creating a custom theme in Wordpress for the website I'm creating

There is a section to autoplay a video media uploaded by the user , like so

**front-page.php :**

```
<div >
            <video src="<?php echo esc_url(get_theme_mod('theme_custom_video', 'videos/offroading_video.mp4')); ?>"
                autoplay muted loop></video>
 </div>
```

**functions.php**

```
function theme_customizer_settings($wp_customize)
{
    // Register Custom Video Setting
    $wp_customize->add_setting('theme_custom_video', array(
        'default' => '',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_url_raw',
    )
    );

    // Add Control for Custom Video Setting
    $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Media_Control($wp_customize, 'theme_custom_video', array(
        'label' => __('Custom Video', 'theme'),
        'section' => 'title_tagline',
        'mime_type' => 'video',
    )
    ));
}
add_action('customize_register', 'theme_customizer_settings');
```

The label and space for choosing an image sure appears, but after selecting the uploaded .mp4 file , the video does not display in the theme web page.

After inspecting the element in the devtools , I noticed that the src attribute value is `https://35` instead of the actual url of the video in the wordpress media library .

Also after hitting publish and refreshing the page , the video chosen earlier seems to have disappeared (no video chosen state).

how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `theme_custom_video` field returns the ID of the attachment. To get the URL of the attachment use the [wp_get_attachment_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_url/) function go get the URL based on the attachment ID.

```php
<?php 
$attachment_id = get_theme_mod('theme_custom_video');
$image = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id); ?>

<div>
  <video src="<?php echo esc_url($image); ?>" autoplay muted loop></video>
</div>
```